# Prove that if $M$ is a simple left $R$-module, $Ann(m)$ is a maximal left ideal of $R$ and $M \cong R/Ann(m)$ for all $m \in M\backslash \{0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I need to prove equivalent statements of a simple left $R$-module. However, I'm stuck at the following:

> The map $\phi_m: R/Ann(m) \rightarrow M$, such that $\phi_m(r+Ann(m)) = rm$ for all $r + Ann(m) \in R/Ann(m)$ is a well-defined $R$-module isomorphism for all $m \in M\backslash \{0\}$.

implies

> $Ann(m)$ is a maximal left ideal of $R$ and $M \cong R/Ann(m)$ for all $m \in M\backslash \{0\}$.

Note that $M$ is a nonzero $R$-module.

I need help in proving that $Ann(m)$ is a maximal left ideal of $R$. Please strictly use the statement above and not other definition of simple ring. The latter is obvious.

Comment: If you're assuming $M$ is simple then this follows from the correspondence theorem (4th iso thm), since there is a bijection between submodules of $R/Ann(m)$ and submodules of $R$ containing $Ann(m)$.

Comment: @Jose27 I need to prove that the first statement implies the second statement without using any other things. I know that using the definition of simple ring is easy but now I need to prove the equivalence statement of simple ring. There are actually 5 statements, I can prove the rest, only this part i am stuck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the map $\phi_m$ is surjective we have $M=Rm$ for all $m\in M-\{0\}$. Suppose $\mathrm{Ann}(m)$ is not left maximal for some $m\in M-\{0\}$. Then there is $\mathrm{Ann}(m)\subsetneq I\subsetneq R$ a left ideal. Let $a\in I-\mathrm{Ann}(m)$. Then $am\ne 0$, and $M=R(am)$. Since $M=Rm$ we get $m\in R(am)$, so there is $r\in R$ such that $m=ram$, that is, $(ra-1)m=0$ which implies $ra-1\in\mathrm{Ann}(m)$, hence $ra-1\in I$. But $ra\in I$, so $1\in I$, a contradiction.

Comment: I don't quite understand your proof, Why $M = R(am)$. Since $M= Rm we get m \in R(am)$

Comment: Read again the first sentence of my answer and notice that $am\in M-\{0\}$.